# There has been an awakening...but of what exactly?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, title-explanation

Snoke says to Kylo Ren:

> There has been an awakening. Have you felt it?
>
> ...
>
> The dark side and the light...

It seems clear throughout *Episode VII* that Rey is waking up to her own potential, and that Kylo Ren takes definite steps to solidify his position with the Dark Side. Do these events represent the extent of Snoke's comments or is he hinting at broader events and possibilities?

How should we understand this "awakening"? I'm hoping that the novelizations shed additional context.